# Install contained setup from temporary folder in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

My application requires a computer voice.

I have programmed this computer voice, so I simply put the voice computer setup into my Inno Setup script like this and run it during the installation of my appplication:

```
[Files]
Source: "d:\dev\projects\voice\compiled\upload\voice_setup.exe"; DestDir: "{app}\redist\tts\";

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\redist\tts\voice_setup.exe"; StatusMsg: "Installing voice"; Parameters: "/VERYSILENT";
```

I did it like this because I imagined the user might want to distribute the voice setup. However, I don't want this anymore. Instead, the user should not "get in contact" with this voice setup file.

Obviously I don't find the correct search term to find a sample on how to solve this problem.

Can anybody help and tell me how I could install the contained voice setup without actually copying the voice setup to a directory where the user could easily find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy the sub-installer to [`{tmp}`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=tmp):

```
[Files]
Source: "d:\dev\projects\voice\compiled\upload\voice_setup.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}";

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\voice_setup.exe"; StatusMsg: "Installing voice"; \
    Parameters: "/VERYSILENT";
```

The `{tmp}` gets automatically deleted at the end of the installation.

---

*Though as it is your (sub-)installer, why don't you merge its code into your main installer?*

Comment: Thank you! I didn't merge its code with the main installer as I wanted the voice to have its own Uninstall entry, etc.